# android WebView cannot show the image in release mode

Tags: android, webview

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this.context);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "...<img src="my_pic.png ..."", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

the html is actually in string, i just made it easy to read.

I used above code to populate some html to a WebView to display an image in drawable,
it is fine in debug mode, but a broken image icon results if I install a apk directly.

i am suspecting proguard, but seems doesn't make sense.
anyone experienced please help me ...
thank you

Comment: Did you ever find the reason,  just started getting this problem today.  frustrating because when i created a dev build so i can use the chrome inspector, it works ok.

Comment: Found my problem.  The image was being served by a server that had an untrusted certificate.  I needed to put the whole cert chain on the server(root, intermediary) since it was not for a cert creator that android trusts.  Reason it worked on debugging mode is because android is not a stringent concerning certs in debug mode